# Approximating the integral of a curve using a sequence of line segments

Tags: calculus

> Let $f$ be Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$. Prove that for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a function $g$, continuous on $[a,b]$, such that $$\int_a^b\left(f(x)-g(x)\right)\,dx<\epsilon.$$

**My progress**

*I want to make a function that looks like it's getting close to $f$ as I refine a partition to an infinite number of points.  By drawing, I think the easiest way is to make lines on the partition intervals.*

Let $\mathcal{P}=\{p_0,\dotsc, p_n\}$ be a partition of $[a,b]$.  Define $$g(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}\frac{p_1-x}{p_1-p_0}f(p_0) + \frac{-p_0+x}{p_1-p_0}f(p_1)&=&p_0\leq x\leq p_1 \\ 
\frac{p_2-x}{p_2-p_1}f(p_1) + \frac{-p_1+x}{p_2-p_1}f(p_2)&=&p_1\leq x\leq p_2 \\ 
 &\vdots &\\
\frac{p_n-x}{p_n-p_{n-1}}f(p_{n-1}) + \frac{-p_n+x}{p_n-p_{n-1}}f(p_n)&=&p_{n-1}\leq x\leq p_n
\end{array}\right..$$

- **Continuity**: It's obvious that $g$ is continuous on $(p_{k-1},p_k)$.  To show that it is continuous at the endpoints of each of these intervals (i.e. at each $p_k$), we observe that at these points, $$
  \require{cancel}g(p_k)=\cancelto{0}{\frac{p_k-p_k}{p_k-p_{k-1}}}f(p_{k-1})+\cancelto{1}{\frac{-p_{k-1}+p_k}{p_k-p_{k-1}}}f(p_{k})=f(p_k)$$

*Now what I want is to show that $\int_a^b f-g$ gets small as I increase these number of points to the amount that I need, given an $\epsilon$.  To do this, I have to get some kind of bound on $\int_a^b f-g$.  For the life of me, I can't figure out how to do this.  It seems like it should be some mean value theorem thing, but I need a hint.  From drawing, I can't push away my doubt that I could have selected my $p_i$'s so that $f(p_i)=0$ for all of them.*

Answer (score 0):

Comment with formulas: take
$M_k=\sup f$ in $I_k$, $m_k=\inf f$ in $I_k$. As $g(p_k)=f(p_k)$ and linear between subinterval ends, the bounding of $f-g$ in $I_k$ is simply:
$$|f(x)-g(x)|\le M_k-m_k.$$

Comment: How do I proceed from there?  I'm having trouble showing that this can get smaller than $\epsilon/n$, since $n$ has to get bigger in order to make more partitions.

Comment: @wheelamalees, use that (upper Riemann sum) - (lower Riemann sum) can be as small as you want.