# Every Riemann Integrable Function can be approximated by a Continuous Function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, continuity, self-learning

> Prove that given any Riemann Integrable function $f$ on $[a,b]$, and given any $\varepsilon>0$ one can find a continuous function $g$  on $[a,b]$ such that $$\int_a^b|f(x)-g(x)|dx<\varepsilon $$

I could not even start this problem, except having some stray ideas. Some thoughts are using  Step functions but they are piecewise continuous only.

Please give me some hints only on how to construct such a $g$. Also, please note that I wish to solve this WITHOUT using Weierstrauss Approximating Polynomials.

Comment: Shorten the steps a little, and connect the endpoints with straight line segments.

Comment: Given a step function $f$, there exists a continuous function $g$ with the desired property. So maybe you can show that any Riemann-integrable function can be so approximated by step functions, which in turn can be so approximated by continuous functions.

Comment: David Mitra sorry I could not follow your hint. End points of what? Might you kindly elaborate just a little more?
@HowDoIMath I do not know that for any step function there exists an approximating continuous function. So I must prove that first, which basically solves the problem because then we would just need a Triangle Inequality and we would be done.

Comment: @yedaynara What David writes is a method for approximating step functions with continuous functions. Take a step function, and shorten each step slightly. In the space obtained, connect adjacent steps with (steep) straight line segments. Is this clear?

Comment: The endpoints of the "shortened steps". For example if the step function $s$ is equal to $c$ on $[0,1/2)$ and $d$ on $[1/2,1]$, define the continuous $g$ as follows: $g$ has the value $c$ on $[0,1/2-\epsilon]$, the value $d$ on $[1/2+\epsilon,1]$, and is linear on $(1/2-\epsilon,1/2+\epsilon)$.

Comment: Thanks. I will try the problem now in this direction.

Comment: See this [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1052824/approximating-the-integral-of-a-curve-using-a-sequence-of-line-segments).

Comment: An alternative is just to consider the convolution with a smooth and concentrated kernel like $e^{-nx^2}$.

Comment: Thanks to David Mitra and HowDoIMath, I solved the problem using their hints.

Comment: Maybe you would kindly consider looking at this question which I asked but no (satisfactory) answer has been obtained. This is NOT off-topic for this question because I think that the concept of approximating a Riemann Integrable function by a continuous function can be applied here. The link is: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1138633/if-f-in-ra-b-then-lim-h-to0-int-cdfxh-fxdx-0/1138635?noredirect=1#comment2323789_1138635