# Existence of Derivative for an Integral

Tags: derivatives, riemann-integration

> Let $f$ be a Riemann integrable function defined on $[-2,2]$. Define a function $F \colon (-1,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ by $$F(h)=\int_0^1 h | f(x+h)-f(x)|\, dx.$$ Show that the derivative $F'(0)$ exists.

I started form $\lim_{h\to 0}$ $\frac{F(h)-F(0)}{h}$

By definition, $F(0)=0$ since it $F(0)$ becomes a definite integral of zero.

$\lim_{h\to 0}$ $\frac{F(h)-F(0)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0}$ $\frac{F(h)}{h} = $$\lim_{h\to 0}\int_0^1 |f(x+h)-f(x)| dx$. Them I have no clue to continue, can anyone give me some hints?

Comment: Do you know about the $L^p$ spaces?

Comment: Hint: If $f$ were increasing, then could you solve it (first step: can you write this as two integrals over smaller domains)?

Comment: A possible idea is to approximate $f$ with a (uniformly) continuous function: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1139040/every-riemann-integrable-function-can-be-approximated-by-a-continuous-function

Comment: @AhmedHussein I have seen $L^p$ in my functional analysis, but we use it as an example illustrate the convergence of cauchy sequence.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Like $\lim_{h\to 0}\int_0^1 |f(x+h)-f(x)| dx$ =$\lim_{h\to 0}\int_0^c f(x+h)-f(x) dx+\int_c^1 f(x+h)-f(x) dx$ ?

Comment: This is a good first step, but there is some cancellation because the regions of integration for $f(x+h)$ and $f(x)$ overlap.

Comment: @MichaelBurr It becomes $\lim_{h\to 0} \int_0^h f(x)+\int_1^{1+h} f(x)$ ? Because the value of $f(x)$ between $[h,1]$ cancel each other?

Answer (score 1):

Sine $f$ is integrable, given $\epsilon>0$ there is a partition $P=\{x_0,x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ of $[0,1]$ such that $0\le\int_0^1f-L(P)\le\epsilon$, where $L(P)$ is the lower sum of $f$ associated to the partition $P$. Define $g\colon[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ as
$$
g(x)=\inf_{x_{i-1}\le x<x_i}f(x)\quad\text{on}\quad[x_{i-1},x_i),\quad 1\le i\le N,\quad g(x_N)=g(x_{N-1}).
$$
Then $g$ is integrable, $\int_0^1g=L(P)$ and
$$
0\le f(x)-g(x),\quad0\le\int_0^1(f-g)\le\epsilon.
$$
Then
$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1|f(x+h)-h(x)|\,dx&\le\int_0^1(|f(x+h)-g(x+h)|+|g(x+h)-g(x)|+|g(x)-f(x)|)\,dx\\
&=\int_0^1((f(x+h)-g(x+h))+|g(x+h)-g(x)|+(f(x)-g(x)))\,dx\\
&\le2\,\epsilon+\int_0^1|g(x+h)-g(x)|\,dx.
\end{align}$$
All is left is to show that the last integral converges to $0$ as $h\to0$. This is easy, because $g$ is piecewise constant.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do we have definition for $g(x+h)$ when$x\lt 1-h$?, since we need g(x+h) to be well defined for  $x\lt 1-h$ so as to define $\int_0^1 (f-g)$ ?

Comment: The last integral is $\le 2h*2M*N$, where $M=\sup|g(x)|$? Since$|g(x+h)-g(x)|=0 $ on $[x_i-1+h,x_i-h] $  Thus it coverges to zero.

Comment: Define it to be equal to the value in $x_N=1$.